# How to fetch data from custom table using REST API in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api, magento2.3.5-p2

How can we fetch Custom table data by using Magento 2 REST API ?

Comment: What data you want to fetch.

Comment: I have a custom table with 5 fields. I want to provide that data to others as REST API in Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following things.

1. Confirm you have model for your custom table data save/edit.
2. Create the custom REST API for your extension according to your requirement.
3. Given the REST API URL which you created to other, who need to use that one.